# jQuery Cycle plugin - prevent slide change on pager click

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm creating a simple slideshow, with "pager" as visual info about changing slides (they are bullets, and active one is in diffrent color). 
The thing is - I doesn't want pager elements to be clickable.
How should I prevent this bechavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that it works, but you can try to reset `pagerEvent` value:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    pagerEvent: null
});
```

Default `pagerEvent` value is `click.cycle`, so you need to reset it.